# What is the post-hoc power in my experiment?

Tags: probability, statistics

I often see the claim that post-hoc power is nonsense. 
However, it is unclear what the post-hoc power they criticize is.

> **My Question**
>   What is the post-hoc power in the following experiment?

> **Experiment**:
>   We randomly divide 20 animals into two groups, Group A and Group B.
>   After that, for Group A, Foods A are fed, and for Group B, Foods B are fed. After a certain period, bodyweight
>   was measured, and the data were as follows.
>
> Group_A :40.2, 40.4, 40.6, 40.8, 41.0, 41.2, 41.4, 41.6, 41.8
>   Group_B :30.1, 30.3, 30.5, 30.7, 30.9, 31.1, 31.3, 31.5, 31.7, 31.9, 32.1
>
> I would like to conduct a two-sided test with a significance level of 0.05 to see if there is a significant difference between the two groups.

I think it is one of the following ones. Both codes are written in "R".
R source codes can be downloaded from the following [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GIIZ7iK3Nycm6_-fcEeY0bLKnGevAMUl).

**Method 1**

```
#Load data
Group_A = c(40.2, 40.4, 40.6, 40.8, 41.0, 41.2, 41.4, 41.6, 41.8)
Group_B = c(30.1, 30.3, 30.5, 30.7, 30.9, 31.1, 31.3, 31.5, 31.7, 31.9, 32.1)

# Welch Two Sample t-test
t.test(Group_A,Group_B)

library(effsize)
library(pwr)

cd = cohen.d(Group_A, Group_B)
cd

pwr.t2n.test(n1 = 9, n2= 11, d = cd$estimate, sig.level = 0.05, power = NULL,
         alternative = c("two.sided"))
```

**Method 2**

```
# Load data
Group_A = c(40.2, 40.4, 40.6, 40.8, 41.0, 41.2, 41.4, 41.6, 41.8)
Group_B = c(30.1, 30.3, 30.5, 30.7, 30.9, 31.1, 31.3, 31.5, 31.7, 31.9, 32.1)

# Welch Two Sample t-test
twel=t.test(Group_A,Group_B)
twel

pwel=twel$p.value

library(effsize)
library(pwr)

cd = cohen.d(Group_A, Group_B)
cd

pwr.t2n.test(n1 = 9, n2= 11, d = cd$estimate, sig.level = pwel, power = NULL, 
  alternative = c("two.sided"))
```

Which is the “correct” post-hoc power calculation code?

> Notes:
>   If your "R" environment does not have packages named "effsize" and "pwr", you need to install them previously.　If the following command is executed on R while connected to the Internet, installation should start automatically.

```
install.packages("effsize")
install.packages("pwr")
```

**P.S.**
I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions. I welcome any corrections and English review. (You can edit my question and description to improve them)

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but the English is totally fine.

Comment: I think you will get more interesting responses at stats.stackexchange.com our sister-site dedicated to statistics (also it deserves to be better known). I flagged for 'automatic transfer'

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen
Thank you for checking my English.

Comment: @ Vincent  Thank you for the advice. Thank you for creating a link for cross-validation. Please tell me where the link to my page is in "Cross Validation"?